# Play video options on my website via iOS

Tags: javascript, ios, video-streaming, fullscreen

So, as I searched, I found that is a little problem to play inline videos (no full-screen).

1. But still, there is a way to play videos inline?
2. If there isn't way without make an app, do you know a way to play video on full screen and show elements on the screen while the video is playing?

The best solution I found is to play video on full-screen and "alert" message that jumped based on video time.

Maybe there is a way to show a "div" element just to show text on that full-screen video, without use "alert" that needed to click "ok" every show?

Thanks